# Script runs smoothly from start to finish, but the expected result doesn't happen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, social-networking

The project aims to study a new social media:

https://booyah.live/

My needs are:

**1** - Collect data from profiles that follow a specific profile.

**2** - My account use this data to follow the collected profiles.

**3** - Among other possible options, also unfollow the profiles I follow.

The problem found in the current script:

The profile data in theory is being collected, the script runs perfectly until the end, but for some reason I can't specify, instead of following all the collected profiles, it only follows the base profile.

For example:

I want to follow all 250 profiles that follow the ID `123456`

I activate the `booyahGetAccounts(123456);` script

In theory the end result would be my account following 250 profiles

But the end result I end up following only the `123456` profile, so the count of people I'm following is 1

Complete Project Script:

```
const csrf = 'MY_CSRF_TOKEN';
async function booyahGetAccounts(uid, type = 'followers', follow = 1) {
    if (typeof uid !== 'undefined' && !isNaN(uid)) {
        const loggedInUserID = window.localStorage?.loggedUID;
        if (uid === 0) uid = loggedInUserID;
        const unfollow = follow === -1;
        if (unfollow) follow = 1;
        if (loggedInUserID) {
            if (csrf) {
                async function getUserData(uid) {
                    const response = await fetch(`https://booyah.live/api/v3/users/${uid}`),
                          data = await response.json();
                    return data.user;
                }
                const loggedInUserData = await getUserData(loggedInUserID),
                      targetUserData = await getUserData(uid),
                      followUser = uid => fetch(`https://booyah.live/api/v3/users/${loggedInUserID}/followings`, { method: (unfollow ? 'DELETE' : 'POST'), headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': csrf }, body: JSON.stringify({ followee_uid: uid, source: 43 }) }),
                      logSep = (data = '', usePad = 0) => typeof data === 'string' && usePad ? console.log((data ? data + ' ' : '').padEnd(50, '━')) : console.log('━'.repeat(50),data,'━'.repeat(50));
                async function getList(uid, type, follow) {
                    const isLoggedInUser = uid === loggedInUserID;
                    if (isLoggedInUser && follow && !unfollow && type === 'followings') {
                        follow = 0;
                        console.warn('You alredy follow your followings. `follow` mode switched to `false`. Followings will be retrieved instead of followed.');
                    }
                    const userData = await getUserData(uid),
                          totalCount = userData[type.slice(0,-1)+'_count'] || 0,
                          totalCountStrLength = totalCount.toString().length;
                    if (totalCount) {
                        let userIDsLength = 0;
                        const userIDs = [],
                              nickname = userData.nickname,
                              nicknameStr = `${nickname ? ` of ${nickname}'s ${type}` : ''}`,
                              alreadyFollowedStr = uid => `User ID ${uid} already followed by ${loggedInUserData.nickname} (Account #${loggedInUserID})`;
                        async function followerFetch(cursor = 0) {
                            const fetched = [];
                            await fetch(`https://booyah.live/api/v3/users/${uid}/${type}?cursor=${cursor}&count=100`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                                const list = data[type.slice(0,-1)+'_list'];
                                if (list?.length) fetched.push(...list.map(e => e.uid));
                                if (fetched.length) {
                                    userIDs.push(...fetched);
                                    userIDsLength += fetched.length;
                                    if (follow) followUser(uid);
                                    console.log(`${userIDsLength.toString().padStart(totalCountStrLength)} (${(userIDsLength / totalCount * 100).toFixed(4)}%)${nicknameStr} ${follow ? 'followed' : 'retrieved'}`);
                                    if (fetched.length === 100) {
                                        followerFetch(data.cursor);
                                    } else {
                                        console.log(`END REACHED. ${userIDsLength} accounts ${follow ? 'followed' : 'retrieved'}.`);
                                        if (!follow) logSep(targetList);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        await followerFetch();
                        return userIDs;
                    } else {
                        console.log(`This account has no ${type}.`);
                    }
                }
                logSep(`${follow ? 'Following' : 'Retrieving'} ${targetUserData.nickname}'s ${type}`, 1);
                const targetList = await getList(uid, type, follow);
            } else {
                console.error('Missing CSRF token. Retrieve your CSRF token from the Network tab in your inspector by clicking into the Network tab item named "bug-report-claims" and then scrolling down in the associated details window to where you see "x-csrf-token". Copy its value and store it into a variable named "csrf" which this function will reference when you execute it.');
            }
        } else {
            console.error('You do not appear to be logged in. Please log in and try again.');
        }
    } else {
        console.error('UID not passed. Pass the UID of the profile you are targeting to this function.');
    }
}
```

This current question is a continuation of that answer from the link:

[Collect the full list of buttons to follow without having to scroll the page (DevTools Google Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840127/collect-the-full-list-of-buttons-to-follow-without-having-to-scroll-the-page-de/68028272#68028272)

Since I can't offer more bounty on that question, I created this one to offer the new bounty to anyone who can fix the bug and make the script work.

> Access account on Booyah website to use for tests:
>
> Access by google:
>
> User: teststackoverflowbooyah@gmail.com
>
> Password: quartodemilha

Comment: Instead of `if (follow) followUser(uid);` in your `followerFetch` function shouldn't you iterate over `userIDs` and call `followUser` on each one of them? The thing is we can't test the code in any way neither do we have any API reference provided to verify correctness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to admit that it is really hard to read your code, I spent a lesser amount of time rewriting everything from scratch.

Stated that we need a code piece to be cut/pasted in the JavaScript console of web browsers able to store some data (i.e. expiration of followings and permanent followings) we need some considerations.

We can consider *expiration of followings* as volatile data: something that if lost can be reset to 1 day later from when we loose this data. **window.localStorage** is a perfect candidate to store these kind of data. If we change web browser the only drawback is that we loose the *expiration of followings* and we can tolerate to reset them to 1 day later from when we change browser.

While to store the list of *permanent followings* we need a permanent store even if we change web browser. The best idea that came to my mind is to create an alternative account with which to follow the users we never want to stop following. In my code I used `uid 3186068` (a random user), once you have created your own alternative account, just replace the first line of the code block with its **uid**.

Another thing we need to take care is *error handling*: API could always have errors. The approach I chosen is to write `myFetch` which, in case of errors, retries twice the same call; if the error persists, probably we are facing a temporary *booyah.live* outage. Probably we just need to retry a bit later.

To try to provide a comfortable interface, the code blocks gathers the **uid** from **window.location**: to follow the followers of users, just cut/paste the code block on tabs opened on their profiles. For example I run the code from a tab open on `https://booyah.live/studio/123456?source=44`.

Last, to unfollow users the `clean` function is called 5 minutes later we paste the code (to not conflict with calls to follow followers) and than is executed one hour later it finishes its job. It is written to access the **localStorage** in an atomic way, so you can have many of them running simultaneously on different tabs of the same browser, you can not care about it. The only thing you need to take care it that when the **window.location** changes, all the JavaScript events in the tab are reset; so I suggest to keep a tab open on the home page, paste the code block on it, and forget about this tab; it will be the tab responsible of unfollowing users. Then open other tabs to do what you need, when you hit a user you want to follow the followers, paste the block on it, wait the job is finished and continue to use the tab normally.

```
// The account we use to store followings
const followingsUID = 3186068;
// Gather the loggedUID from window.localStorage
const { loggedUID } = window.localStorage;
// Gather the CSRF-Token from the cookies
const csrf = document.cookie.split("; ").reduce((ret, _) => (_.startsWith("session_key=") ? _.substr(12) : ret), null);

// APIs could have errors, let's do some retries
async function myFetch(url, options, attempt = 0) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://booyah.live/api/v3/" + url, options);
    const ret = await res.json();

    return ret;
  } catch(e) {
    // After too many consecutive errors, let's abort: we need to retry later
    if(attempt === 3) throw e;

    return myFetch(url, option, attempt + 1);
  }
}

function expire(uid, add = true) {
  const { followingsExpire } = window.localStorage;
  let expires = {};

  try {
    // Get and parse followingsExpire from localStorage
    expires = JSON.parse(followingsExpire);
  } catch(e) {
    // In case of error (ex. new browsers) simply init to empty
    window.localStorage.followingsExpire = "{}";
  }

  if(! uid) return expires;

  // Set expire after 1 day
  if(add) expires[uid] = new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 24 * 1000;
  else delete expires[uid];

  window.localStorage.followingsExpire = JSON.stringify(expires);
}

async function clean() {
  try {
    const expires = expire();
    const now = new Date().getTime();

    for(const uid in expires) {
      if(expires[uid] < now) {
        await followUser(parseInt(uid), false);
        expire(uid, false);
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {}

  // Repeat clean in an hour
  window.setTimeout(clean, 3600 * 1000);
}

async function fetchFollow(uid, type = "followers", from = 0) {
  const { cursor, follower_list, following_list } = await myFetch(`users/${uid}/${type}?cursor=${from}&count=50`);
  const got = (type === "followers" ? follower_list : following_list).map(_ => _.uid);
  const others = cursor ? await fetchFollow(uid, type, cursor) : [];

  return [...got, ...others];
}

async function followUser(uid, follow = true) {
  console.log(`${follow ? "F" : "Unf"}ollowing ${uid}...`);
  return myFetch(`users/${loggedUID}/followings`, {
    method:  follow ? "POST" : "DELETE",
    headers: { "X-CSRF-Token": csrf },
    body:    JSON.stringify({ followee_uid: uid, source: 43 })
  });
}

async function doAll() {
  if(! loggedUID) throw new Error("Can't get 'loggedUID' from localStorage: try to login again");
  if(! csrf) throw new Error("Can't get session token from cookies: try to login again");

  console.log("Fetching current followings...");
  const currentFollowings = await fetchFollow(loggedUID, "followings");

  console.log("Fetching permanent followings...");
  const permanentFollowings = await fetchFollow(followingsUID, "followings");

  console.log("Syncing permanent followings...");
  for(const uid of permanentFollowings) {
    expire(uid, false);

    if(currentFollowings.indexOf(uid) === -1) {
      await followUser(uid);
      currentFollowings.push(uid);
    }
  }

  // Sync followingsExpire in localStorage
  for(const uid of currentFollowings) if(permanentFollowings.indexOf(uid) === -1) expire(uid);
  // Call first clean task in 5 minutes
  window.setTimeout(clean, 300 * 1000);

  // Gather uid from window.location
  const match = /\/studio\/(\d+)/.exec(window.location.pathname);

  if(match) {
    console.log("Fetching this user followers...");
    const followings = await fetchFollow(parseInt(match[1]));

    for(const uid of followings) {
      if(currentFollowings.indexOf(uid) === -1) {
        await followUser(uid);
        expire(uid);
      }
    }
  }

  return "Done";
}

await doAll();
```

**The problem: I strongly suspect a booyah.live API bug**

To test my code I run it from `https://booyah.live/studio/123456?source=44`.

If I run it multiple times I continue to get following output:

```
Fetching current followings...
Fetching permanent followings...
Syncing permanent followings...
Following 1801775...
Following 143823...
Following 137017...
Fetching this user followers...
Following 16884042...
Following 16166724...
```

**There is bug somewhere!** The expected output for subsequent executions in the same tab would be:

```
Fetching current followings...
Fetching permanent followings...
Syncing permanent followings...
Fetching this user followers...
```

After seeking the bug in my code without success, I checked *booyah.live* APIs: if I navigate following URLs (the **uid**s are the ones the code continue to follow in subsequent executions)

```
https://booyah.live/studio/1801775
https://booyah.live/studio/143823
https://booyah.live/studio/137017
https://booyah.live/studio/16884042
https://booyah.live/studio/16166724
```

I can clearly see I follow them, but if I navigate `https://booyah.live/following` (the list of users I follow) I can't find them, neither if I scroll the page till the end.

Since I do exactly the same calls the website does, I strongly suspect the bug is in *booyah.live* APIs, exactly in the way they handle the `cursor` parameter.

I suggest you to open a support ticket to *booyah.live* support team. You could use the test account you provided us: I already provided you the details to do that. ;)

Comment: Ok, that's what I would like to know, if I could put it back and it would remove all or if I lost the data from the previous page, it wouldn't be able to stop following it, thanks and we can delete these messages. I'll do the tests soon and if everything goes perfectly I'll mark the award for you!

Comment: I would appreciate that so much @BrondbyIF ! Thank you.

Comment: Hi @BrondbyIF , did you open the support ticket I suggested? I'm so curious about their answer

Comment: Hi @DanieleRicci Hello friend, there was a death in my family and I had to leave my things to be present, sorry for not having finished the question, I will do it as soon as I get home

Comment: That's so sad. I'm with you @BrondbyIF . Think to your family. Bugs can wait...

Comment: Hey @DanieleRicci Thanks for the support message! I wish you all the best! About the code, I did a test on my private account, I put it to follow 2 million profiles, but when it went unfollowed they gave an error and didn't stop following anyone. Can you imagine a solution to this problem?

Comment: Now I don't know what to do following so many profiles, is there any way to stop following in blocks every 50 profiles for example, instead of trying to collect all of them first before starting to stop following?

Comment: If you can help me, I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: I've already given you the 500 prize pool, this extra help would only be if you can really help me.

Comment: OMG @BrondbyIF ! 2M followings! Try this: `window.localStorage.followingsExpire={} ; for(const uid of (await fetchFollow(loggedUID, "followings"))) await followUser(uid, false);` (after pasted the code) and give me some feedback. Now is sleep time here in Italy, if it doesn't work, let's speak tomorrow. BTW, TY for the bounty! And plz try to increase the number of following a bit more smoothly ;)

Comment: Hi @DanieleRicci, Unfortunately it does the path ```Fetching current followings...```, ```Fecthing permanent followings...```, ```Syncing permanent followings``` | and a message appears on the screen: ```Debugging connection was closed. Reason: Render process gone. Reconnect when ready by reopening DevTools.``` Is there any simple option that you could add separately where it stops following in blocks of 1,000 profiles, for example, according to which it collects the profiles instead of collecting all of them and then starting to stop following?

Comment: Maybe that way I could solve this stupid thing I did, I hope you can help me, I shouldn't have done what I did, I didn't think about the disaster that could happen.

Comment: Hi @BrondbyIF , it seems that what you described happen after you pasted the code block: you paste the code, it starts working and after a while you get that error message. If that's the case, you could paste the code block **without the last line** the one `await doAll()` , then paste the same code in my last comment.

Comment: Hi @BrondbyIF , how is going? Was you able to clean all the following and restart from a clean state? And moreover, had you open the support request I suggested? I'm so curios about their answer

Comment: Hi @DanieleRicci, How are you? So...  Unfortunately it manages to stop following about 200,000 profiles and then DevTools closes by itself, then it has to start the process all over again. My computer is very good, so closing DevTools has nothing to do with lack of memory or something because of the computer's fault.

Comment: But I'm making 200,000 out of 200,000. Haha. If you imagine something that can solve this bug, it would be nice, but in its current form it's already helping me a lot.

Comment: Hi @BrondbyIF, could you point me some uid with tons on followings so I can try to reproduce the problem? (I need to understand which is the breaking point, I suspect **localStorage**, but I prefer to reproduce the problem in order to investigate it). But before this, **did you open the support request I told** ? :) with this huge numbers, and that bug alive, I think it is very hard to make the script free from problems

Comment: Booyah replied saying that nothing prevents us from creating automations on accounts, but that they do not open user requests for the programming sector. Said he wouldn't even forward my message to the technicians. The example of profile: https://booyah.live/studio/42973126

Comment: Hi @DanieleRicci A new error started to appear today:  ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at fetchFollow (<anonymous>:63:71)
    at async fetchFollow (<anonymous>:64:27)
    at async fetchFollow (<anonymous>:64:27)```

Comment: Hi @BrondbyIF, I open another support request, it seems they solved the bug of the cursor, but it seems they still have some problems on first (or last) following/follower. More than this I tried to rework the code, but with the huge numbers you want to use, the localStorage quota is always reached. We should try to drop using the localStorage and try to use IndexDB, but I'm not so strong with it.